# How to find differences between two list of dict?

Tags: python

I have two lists:

```
l1 = [{}]
l2 = [[]]
```

I was trying to find the differences between the two:

```
list(set(l1) - set(l2))
```

But received the error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

What's the best way to find the diffs in this situation?

Comment: In the case of the `dict`, are you interested in comparing its `keys` to the list or its `values`?

Comment: value for one key only.

Comment: Please fix your example data. `l1, l2` are terrible example data, they're both empty, so the result is trivial and you won't be able to catch bugs in code. Also, l2 is a list-of-list, not a list-of-dict as you claimed. Code that assumes it's a list-of-dict is likely to blow up or fail.

Comment: And what does "find the diffs" mean, if l1 is a (non-empty) list-of-dicts and l2 a list-of-lists? Do you only want the diffs on keys/elements, but not values? Are `l1 = [['a']] ; l2 = [{'a': ''foo'}]` the same or different? If different, what are the "diffs'? Show us exactly what output you expect for non-trivial input l1,l2.

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension (for `l1-l2`):
`[i for i in l1 if i not in l2]`